# Formatting pwd/ls for use with scp

Tags: linux, bash, scp, ls, pwd

I have two terminal windows with `bash`. One is local on the `client` computer, another one has an SSH-session on the `server`. On the `server`, I am in a directory and seeing a file I would like to copy to my `client` using scp from the `client`.

On the `server` I see:

```
user@server:/path$ ls filename
filename
```

I can now type `scp` in the `client` shell, select and copy the `user@server:/path` from the `server` shell and paste to the `client` shell, then type slash and copy and paste the `filename` and append a dot to get:

```
user@client:~$ scp user@server:/path/filename .
```

to `scp` a file from the `server` to the `client`.

Now I am searching for a command on the `server`, that would work like this:

```
user@server:/path$ special_ls filename
user@server:/path/filename
```

which would give me the complete scp-ready string to copy&paste to the `client` shell.

Something in the form

```
echo $USER@$HOSTNAME:${pwd}/$filename
```

working with relative/absolute paths.

Is there any such command/switch combination or do I have to hack it myself?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick snippet to print such output for pasting:

```
#!/bin/sh
SCPUSER="myuser"
SERVER="myserver"
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    printf '%s@%s:%s\n' "${SCPUSER}" "${SERVER}" "$(readlink -f "${1}")"
    shift
done
```

The `while; shift` construction enables you to give multiple arguments which will be printed, separated by newlines.

This is straightforward; the "trick" above that you are probably looking for is probably just `readlink`.

You could also e.g. set up either `ssh-agent` or passwordless login via keys (if it is a local server and security is not too strict for this) to wrap `scp` server side to avoid the pasting step and directly `scp` files from the server.

Comment: Thank you, `readlink` is a very good hint, although the rest is hacking. If nobody comes with some already-built-in solution (without need of copying this script to any server), I will accept this answer.